# ng-repeat and ng-if not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I want to do following:

1. Show all the html elements on the page based on some conditions,
   my understanding was i can use ng-if.
2. If employeeList is empty then do i need to create another copy of the inner elements to make sure it shows on the page
3. ng-if prints both divs and spans which only one should be printed my html is this

html:

```
 <div class="container" ng-controller="profileController" ng-init="loadProfilesData()">
    <div ng-repeat="p in profileData">
        <div>{{p.company}}</div>
        <div>{{p.department}}</div>

        <div ng-repeat="emp in p.employeeList"></div>

            <div ng-if="emp.Tag== 'Devo100'" gauge-chart class="gauge" id="Devo100-{{p.Id}}" value=p.Value*100></div>
            <div ng-if="emp.Tag!= 'Devo100'" gauge-chart class="gauge" id="Devo100-{{p.Id}}" value=0></div>

            <span ng-if="emp.Tag== 'Devo102'">
               {{ p.Value | date: "hh:mm:ss" }}
            </span>
            <span ng-if="emp.Tag== 'Devo102'">
               0
            </span>

        </div>
    </div>                
</div>
```

my json is following

```
profileData: [  
                  {
                   ID: "1",
                   metricStatList: [{"Value":0.003,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test0","Tag":"Devo100"}},
                                 {"Value":0.004,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test1","Tag":"Devo101"}},
                                 {"Value":0.005,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test2","Tag":"Devo102"}}],                  
                   comapny: "MSDFT",
                   department: "Sales"
                  },
                  {
                   ID: "2",
                   metricStatList: null,                  
                   comapny: "MSDFT",
                   department: "HR"
                  },
                  {
                   ID: "3",
                   metricStatList: [{"Value":0.003,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test0","Tag":"Devo100"}},
                                 {"Value":0.004,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test1","Tag":"Devo101"}}],                  
                   comapny: "MSDFT",
                   department: "Development"
                  },
                  {
                   ID: "4",
                   metricStatList: [{"Value":0.1,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test2","Tag":"Devo102"}},
                                 {"Value":0.25,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test1","Tag":"Devo101"}}],                  
                   comapny: "MSDFT",
                   department: "Finance"
                  },
                  {
                   ID: "5",
                   metricStatList: [{"Value":0.233,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test0","Tag":"Devo100"}}],                  
                   comapny: "MSDFT",
                   department: "Accounts"
                  }
                ]
```

Comment: It looks like in your code you are referencing `employeeList ` where in the data you have `metricStatList`

Comment: where is employeeList?

Comment: sorry, its actually metricStatList